# Commuting conjugate elements in torsion-free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I have come across the following question while studying projective modules over integral groups rings of torsion-free groups.

Given a non-unit $x\in G$ a torsion-free group, does there exist $g\in G$ such that $g$ and $x^{-1}gx$ are non-equal and commute in $G$. The edge cases of $G$ a free group or free abelian clearly do not satisfy this, and one can verify that this is true for specific examples, but any general results or conditions on $x$ or $G$ would be much appreciated.

A related weaker condition that would be just as useful to hear about is whether given $x\in G/G''$, there exists $g,h\in G$ that commute and the images of $g$ and $h$ in $G/G''$ are conjugate by $x\in G/G''$.

Edit: General question

Fix a torsion free group $G$, we have $G/G''$ metabelian and if $G/G’$ torsion-free, we have $G/G''$ poly(-infinite) cyclic. Hence $G/G''$ has a finite length subnormal series in which each factor is infinite cyclic. Take the minimal $G_j\triangleleft G$ of this series such that $G_j$ non-abelian, and note that $G_j\cong G_{j-1}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$.

Fix any such series as above, and let $x\in G/G''$ be a generator of the above factor $\mathbb{Z}$. Does there exist $g,h\in G$ that are distinct and commute, with images in $G/G''$ that are inside $G_{j-1}$ and that are conjugate by $x\in G/G''$.

I am interested in non-trivial examples of groups with this property.

Comment: For the first question "given a non-unit...", $g=1$ works, and $g=x$ works too. So I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: As @YCor says, any power of $x$ will work.  But what you ask feels close to the  CSA property: if $x$ is non-trivial and $gxg^{-1}$ commutes with $x$ then $g$ commutes with $x$.

Comment: @YCor sorry yes should have specified that I would like the 2 elements non-equal, will edit accordingly

Comment: @HJRW thanks, if I’m not mistaken this means that there is a class of groups that will never satisfy this first property

Comment: Then this is clearly false for abelian groups.

Comment: Well, both free groups and free abelian groups are CSA. (More generally, all toral relatively hyperbolic groups are CSA.) It looks like your claim that they satisfied your property wasn't correct...

Comment: @HJRW yes this condition clearly doesn’t hold for free and free abelian groups, I appreciate the way I wrote it is ambiguous, have edited again

Comment: Oh, I see. Well then, as I said above, all toral relatively hyperbolic groups, including all torsion-free hyperbolic groups, will give you further non-examples. But, to be honest, the question remains somewhat vague. Can you make it more focussed?

Comment: @HJRW thank you for the non-examples. By making the question more focused are you meaning further motivation or something else?

Comment: Well it’s not clear what you want. Are you interested in the element $x$ or the group $G$? Do you want examples or non-examples? The best MO questions admit a yes/no answer. Certainly, a group in which this held for every $x$ seems like it would need to be very special. But the condition $g\neq xgx^{-1}$ looks unnatural.

Comment: @HJRW I see where you are coming from. I guess what I mainly wanted was some general insight into the rarity of such groups with this holding for all x, and your claim that these are rare is useful as I honestly didn’t know where it stood. The conditions seem unnatural mainly because in full generality the question is not very nice to look at but I’ll try to add it in below my previous question.

Comment: @WilliamThomas: Thanks for the edit, which has clarified things somewhat. However, while we now have a well-posed property of a given group $G$, your post is still not strictly a question: are you asking if there is such a $G$ (yes: the trivial group), or if every torsion-free $G$ has this property? At first glance, it looks like your property might be non-trivial even for metabelian polycyclic groups. Perhaps a more focused question would focus on that class?

Comment: @HJRW this may not be satisfactory to you but was interested in non-trivial examples of groups with this property. If I’m not mistaken for the case of metabelian polycyclic groups one can choose any element in $G_{j-1}$ as $G/G”=G$, and it’s conjugate by $x$, then these commute in $G$ as $G_{j-1}$ abelian.

Comment: @HJRW one thing to note is that I think such groups can be computed artificially by choosing a subnormal series of $G/G”$ such that $G’/G”\triangleleft G_{j-1}$ (which can always be done), and then take an element of $G’/G”$ and it’s conjugate and simply quotient out $G$ by the commutator of lifts of each of these elements, and this new group will still have the same metabelian quotient but will have the commuting element as required.

Comment: @WilliamThomas: Your last two comments suggest that you have a complicated notion of "trivial" examples, which you haven't explained in the question. And yet you ask for "non-trivial" examples!

Comment: @HJRW sorry for the confusion, I guess maybe I should’ve been more specific this is kind of why I was reluctant to ask the whole question on here as maybe I’m not quite comfortable enough with what exactly I’m asking for. I think I’ll probably just have to work through examples myself as it appears there is no nice general theory covering this from what you’ve said. But thank you this has definitely helped me understand the details of the question I was thinking about.

Comment: OK, I'm glad it has been helpful. Since the question doesn't appear to admit a well-defined answer, I'm going to vote to close.